# Xcode 6/iOS - Archive & Info.plist missing

Tags: ios, archive, info.plist

I'm trying to create and validate an archive for an iOS app. I can run on the simulators and create the archive, but when I try to validate the archive, I get the following messages :

[image]

The plist location seems properly set in the build settings (when I change it I can no longer run on the simulator).

Any clue of what is missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I just needed to set the "Build" AND "Version" in the "General" tab of my project infos. Setting the value in the plist manually didn't work -_- ...

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Setting the Build and Version in the General tab also fixed this problem for me. I think Version was empty when I first looked at the tab.