# Xcode 6 error when submitting app: doesn't contain info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, info.plist

For some reason I'm getting an error saying doesn't contain info.plist when submitting app through xcode 6 in the application loader. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

https://www.ayballapps.com/apps/files/applications/EA3684FCAEC7DF3C9146836A5/images/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-16%20at%205.28.46%20PM.png

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797043/xcode-6-ios-archive-info-plist-missing for the answer that worked for me